# get rid of global variable in python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, global-variables

First of all I'm using python 3.3 & 3.2 on windows and Linux respectively.

I am starting to build an rpn calculator.  It looks like cross-platform key listeners is a kind of holy grail for python.  So far this seems to be doing the trick, but I've created other problems:

1. I cannot get away from the global variable for entries and using my
   stack.
2. It looks like I have to build the program from inside
   `callback()`

Here is a rough skeleton that shows my direction.  Am I missing a way to pass information in and out of `callback()`

The goal was to build an RPN class before i found myself stuck inside `callback()`.

```
import tkinter as tk

entry = ""
stack = list()

operators = {"+",
            "-",
            "*",
            "/",
            "^",
            "sin",
            "cos",
            "tan"}

def operate(_op):
    if _op == "+":
        print("plus")

def callback(event):
    global entry, stack
    entry = entry + event.char
    if event.keysym == 'Escape': # exit program
        root.destroy()
    elif event.keysym=='Return': # push string onto stack  TODO
        print(entry)
        entry = ""
    elif entry in operators:
        operate(entry)


root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.bind('<Key>', callback)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

You have several options to do what you want to do.

### 1. Use a Class for your application

The canonical way of doing what you wish without resorting to a global variable is to place the application within a class, and pass a method as a callback (see `print_contents`) the following is straight [from the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html):

```
class App(Frame):
  def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.pack()

    self.entrythingy = Entry()
    self.entrythingy.pack()

    # here is the application variable
    self.contents = StringVar()
    # set it to some value
    self.contents.set("this is a variable")
    # tell the entry widget to watch this variable
    self.entrythingy["textvariable"] = self.contents

    # and here we get a callback when the user hits return.
    # we will have the program print out the value of the
    # application variable when the user hits return
    self.entrythingy.bind('<Key-Return>',
                          self.print_contents)

  def print_contents(self, event):
    print("hi. contents of entry is now ---->",
          self.contents.get())
```

### 2. Curry the callback over your state

You can also use Python's [functional programming constructs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to curry a function over a global variable and then pass the curried function as a callback.

```
import functools

global_var = {}

def callback(var, event):
  pass

#...
root.bind('<Key>', functools.partial(callback, global_var))
```

Although this probably isn't what you want.

### 3. Use a global variable

Sometimes, a global variable is ok.

### 4. Re-architect for cleanliness and readability

However, you most definitely do not have to build your program inside the callback.

In fact, I would recommend that you create a suite of test with various valid and invalid input, and make a `Calculator` class or function that takes a string input of RPN commands and returns a value. This is easy to test without a tkinter interface, and will be far more robust.

Then, use your callback to build a string which you pass to your `Calculator`.

If you want incremental calculation (ie, you're building a simulator), then simply make your Calculator accept single tokens rather than entire equations, but the design remains similar. All the state is then encapsulated inside the `Calculator` rather than globally.